# Xiaomi Redmi K20 Pro (2019) phone screen is broken. Touch is working but cannot see anything. How do I access important data through laptop?

Tags: usb, android, data-transfer

I dropped my phone and the screen stopped displaying. Touch is still working but I can't use it because the whole display is black.

Screen repair was costly $150 NZD and would take time, so I bought new phone urgently as I needed an active phone.

Now I want to access the important data on my phone and transfer it to the laptop. I don't have USB debugging on. So, I cannot use software like DroidKit.

I've heard of using a USB C to HDMI hub to display screen on TV and control through a mouse. But I'm not sure if Redmi K20 Pro (2019) since it is a cheap phone, is MHL compliant. And all the USB C to HDMI hubs are very costly, NZD60+. I'm a student so can't afford.

How can I retrieve data from this phone using my laptop?

Comment: Has the device been powered off/restarted since the screen cracked? Had you connected your phone to your computer before? Do you have a cloud drive installed and running on the phone that may be syncing this data already? Android already has built-in backup systems, so long as you turned them on. Modern phones do not usually allow general access to their system contents without confirming, usually using some interaction on the screen, and being able to get around this means breaking legit security features of the device.

Comment: I can't turn off the phone, but yes when the battery dies, I can charge it up and turn it on using the physical power button. I have Google drive installed, but I haven't backed up any data. My contacts, calendar, drive, Gmail, keep notes, tasks are all synced but I need to get my photos and pdfs from the phone memory. Yes, I cannot connect to laptop via USB because I need to click on 'File transfer' option when it pops up, but that's impossible because the screen is black, and I don't know where exactly in the UI the option is located. Continuation in the next comment...

Comment: Yes, so I'm asking for a way to access my data with USB debugging disabled. There are some softwares available, but they are all paid, and I can't afford right now. So, looking for an open-source trusted software to transfer my data. Yes, I guess it will be breaking security features, but I bought a new cheap phone so I'm okay with that. Is it possible to break it?

Comment: Software recommendation requests are not allowed here. We solve problems on PCs, but when someone comes asking for a software tool that sort of question is not allowed. I recommend reading the Help section to understand some of the peculiarities and specifics of this site.

Comment: The question was not IF you can turn the phone off or on, but whether it has already been turned off and back on since the issue. Phones usually have increased security when you first turn them on, and you have to unlock them correctly before you can then access certain functions after a restart. A best case scenario would be that you have already connected your phone to the computer in the past (so the phone trusts the computer) AND you have not restarted or had to power the phone back on since the screen broke, so the security is not enhanced.

Comment: To answer your question: no, you can't do this. IF you could, it would be to take advantage of a significant unpatched security issue with the phone, which may or may not exist or be known. Software claiming to do this will likely be trying to take advantage of unpatched security issues, and there's a good chance it won't work. The most likely way to successfully recover this data is to repair the screen.

Comment: Try asking in other forums for someone who also has K20 Pro (or its twin, Mi 9T Pro) to record the screen when the USB is being plugged in and replicate that in your phone. Note that you also need to unlock your phone, AFAIK first unlock after boot can't use biometrics, you need to use either pattern, pin or password.

Comment: @music2myear thank you for your advice. I'll try my luck now with USB C to HDMI hub with mouse control.

Comment: @Martheen I will also try your solution. Thanks.